# Mapbox Greyed out on dialog/Popup

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my code;

```
dialog = new Dialog(HomeScreen.this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pop_up_request);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: What is the issue ? What do you want ?

Comment: Here is the solution of Mapbox Greyed out issue on dialog/popup

Comment: Show screenshot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can solve issue of greyed out Map box in popup with just change of popup's theme style.
with just change style of dialog.
Like -
dialog = new Dialog(HomeScreen.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

Comment: Can you give an example of the theme style.